# Why does switching shaders in webgl not work

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am drawing a mesh background with two shaders, one for points and one for lines, which are used for drawing point and line meshes respectively. However, for some reason, only the first shader used can work properly, while the other one cannot。

The `renderGridPoint` and `renderGridLine` methods are methods for drawing linear and point meshes, respectively. They execute `gl.useProgram(canvas.programLine)` or `gl.useProgram(canvas. programPoint)` once when switching to a line or point for the first time. However, the second used shader does not take effect, whether trying `programLine` or `programPoint` first

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<style>
    canvas{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    button{
        position:relative;
        z-index: 111;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <canvas ref="bgCanvas"></canvas>
    <button @click="grid = grid !== 'point' ? 'point' : 'line'">change</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<script>
    const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data(){
            return {
                grid: 'none'
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.initBGCanvas();
        },
        methods: {

            initBGCanvas(){
                const canvas = this.$refs.bgCanvas;
                const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
                gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

                const vertexShaderSource = `
                     attribute vec2 aPosition;
                     attribute float a_Size;
                     uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

                     void main() {
                         gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 0, 1);
                         gl_PointSize = a_Size;
                     }
                `;
                canvas.vertexShaderPoint = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
                gl.shaderSource(canvas.vertexShaderPoint, vertexShaderSource);
                gl.compileShader(canvas.vertexShaderPoint);
                canvas.vertexShaderLine = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
                gl.shaderSource(canvas.vertexShaderLine, vertexShaderSource);
                gl.compileShader(canvas.vertexShaderLine);

                const fragmentShaderSourcePoint =  `
                     precision mediump float;
                     uniform vec4 u_color;

                     void main() {
                     float dist = distance(gl_PointCoord,vec2(0.5,0.5));
                     if(dist < 0.5) {
                         gl_FragColor = u_color;
                     }else {
                         discard;
                     }
                     }
                        `;
                canvas.fragmentShaderPoint = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                gl.shaderSource(canvas.fragmentShaderPoint, fragmentShaderSourcePoint);
                gl.compileShader(canvas.fragmentShaderPoint);

                const fragmentShaderSourceLine =  `
                            precision mediump float;
                            uniform vec4 u_color;

                            void main() {
                                    gl_FragColor = u_color;
                            }
                        `;
                canvas.fragmentShaderLine = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                gl.shaderSource(canvas.fragmentShaderLine, fragmentShaderSourceLine);
                gl.compileShader(canvas.fragmentShaderLine);

                canvas.programLine = gl.createProgram();
                canvas.programPoint = gl.createProgram();
                gl.attachShader(canvas.programLine, canvas.vertexShaderLine);
                gl.attachShader(canvas.programLine, canvas.fragmentShaderLine);
                gl.attachShader(canvas.programPoint, canvas.vertexShaderPoint);
                gl.attachShader(canvas.programPoint, canvas.fragmentShaderPoint);
                gl.linkProgram(canvas.programPoint);
                gl.linkProgram(canvas.programLine);

                // canvas.programPoint = canvas.programLine;

                this.renderGrid();
            },

            renderGrid(){
                const canvas = this.$refs.bgCanvas;
                const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

                if(this.grid === 'point'){
                    this.renderGridPoint();
                }else if(this.grid === 'line'){
                    this.renderGridLine();
                }else{
                    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                }
                window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.renderGrid();
                });
            },

            renderGridPoint(){
                const canvas = this.$refs.bgCanvas;
                const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
                const gridSpace = 30;
                const gridSize = 2;

                if(canvas.grid !== 'point'){
                    gl.useProgram(canvas.programPoint);
                    canvas.grid = 'point';
                }

                if(canvas.clientWidth !== canvas.width || canvas.clientHeight !== canvas.height){
                    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
                    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
                    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
                    mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 0, -1, 1);
                    const projectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'uProjectionMatrix');
                    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
                }

                const gridPoints = [];
                for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientWidth; i += gridSpace) {
                    for (let j = 0; j <= canvas.clientHeight; j += gridSpace) {
                        gridPoints.push(i, j);
                    }
                }

                const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

                const color = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'u_color');
                gl.uniform4f(color, 194/255, 194/255, 197/255, 1);

                const aSize = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'a_Size');
                gl.vertexAttrib1f(aSize, gridSize);

                const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'aPosition');
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, gridPoints.length / 2);
            },

            renderGridLine(){
                const canvas = this.$refs.bgCanvas;
                const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
                const gridSpace = 100;
                const gridSize = 1;

                if(canvas.grid !== 'line'){
                    gl.useProgram(canvas.programLine);
                    canvas.grid = 'line';
                }

                if(canvas.clientWidth !== canvas.width || canvas.clientHeight !== canvas.height){
                    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
                    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
                    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
                    mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 0, -1, 1);
                    const projectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programLine, 'uProjectionMatrix');
                    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
                }
                const gridPoints = [];
                for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientWidth; i += gridSpace) {
                    gridPoints.push(i, 0);
                    gridPoints.push(i, canvas.clientHeight);
                }
                for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientHeight; i += gridSpace) {
                    gridPoints.push(0, i);
                    gridPoints.push(canvas.clientWidth, i);
                }

                const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

                const color = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programLine, 'u_color');
                gl.uniform4f(color, 235/255, 237/255, 241/255, 1);

                const aSize = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programLine, 'a_Size');
                gl.vertexAttrib1f(aSize, gridSize);

                const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programLine, 'aPosition');
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, gridPoints.length / 2);
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the second shader does not take effect"? In both methods you're clearing the canvas right before rendering, so only the result of the last executed method should be visible.

Comment: the value of this.grid and canvas.grid never seems to change so only one of your shaders is constantly running and the other one never runs?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only invokes one shader. I modified it to toggle `canvas.grid` between "point" and "line" and their respective shaders and they both work. As LJ mentioned above, you should only run `gl.clear` after both shaders have run to prevent them flickering over each other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body><canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas></body>
<script type="module">
    import { glMatrix, mat4 } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.4.3/+esm'
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    canvas.grid = "point";
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    const vertexShaderSource = `
                     attribute vec2 aPosition;
                     attribute float a_Size;
                     uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

                     void main() {
                         gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 0, 1);
                         gl_PointSize = a_Size;
                     }
                `;
    canvas.vertexShaderPoint = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(canvas.vertexShaderPoint, vertexShaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(canvas.vertexShaderPoint);
    canvas.vertexShaderLine = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(canvas.vertexShaderLine, vertexShaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(canvas.vertexShaderLine);

    const fragmentShaderSourcePoint = `
                     precision mediump float;
                     uniform vec4 u_color;

                     void main() {
                     float dist = distance(gl_PointCoord,vec2(0.5,0.5));
                     if(dist < 0.5) {
                         gl_FragColor = u_color;
                     }else {
                         discard;
                     }
                     }
                        `;
    canvas.fragmentShaderPoint = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(canvas.fragmentShaderPoint, fragmentShaderSourcePoint);
    gl.compileShader(canvas.fragmentShaderPoint);

    const fragmentShaderSourceLine = `
                            precision mediump float;
                            uniform vec4 u_color;

                            void main() {
                                    gl_FragColor = u_color;
                            }
                        `;
    canvas.fragmentShaderLine = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(canvas.fragmentShaderLine, fragmentShaderSourceLine);
    gl.compileShader(canvas.fragmentShaderLine);

    canvas.programLine = gl.createProgram();
    canvas.programPoint = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(canvas.programLine, canvas.vertexShaderLine);
    gl.attachShader(canvas.programLine, canvas.fragmentShaderLine);
    gl.attachShader(canvas.programPoint, canvas.vertexShaderPoint);
    gl.attachShader(canvas.programPoint, canvas.fragmentShaderPoint);
    gl.linkProgram(canvas.programPoint);
    gl.linkProgram(canvas.programLine);

    // canvas.programPoint = canvas.programLine;

    renderGrid();

    function renderGrid() {
        const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

        if (canvas.grid === 'line') {
            renderGridPoint();
        } else if (canvas.grid === 'point') {
            renderGridLine();
        } else {
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            renderGrid();
        });
    }

    function renderGridPoint() {
        const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
        const gridSpace = 30;
        const gridSize = 2;

        if (canvas.grid !== 'point') {
            gl.useProgram(canvas.programPoint);
            canvas.grid = 'point';
        }


        // if (canvas.clientWidth !== canvas.width || canvas.clientHeight !== canvas.height) {
        canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
        gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
        mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 0, -1, 1);
        const projectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'uProjectionMatrix');
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
        // }

        const gridPoints = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientWidth; i += gridSpace) {
            for (let j = 0; j <= canvas.clientHeight; j += gridSpace) {
                gridPoints.push(i, j);
            }
        }

        const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        const color = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'u_color');
        gl.uniform4f(color, 194 / 255, 194 / 255, 197 / 255, 1);

        const aSize = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'a_Size');
        gl.vertexAttrib1f(aSize, gridSize);

        const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programPoint, 'aPosition');
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, gridPoints.length / 2);
    }

    function renderGridLine() {
        const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
        const gridSpace = 100;
        const gridSize = 1;

        if (canvas.grid !== 'line') {
            gl.useProgram(canvas.programLine);
            canvas.grid = 'line';
        }

        // if (canvas.clientWidth !== canvas.width || canvas.clientHeight !== canvas.height) {
        canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
        gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
        mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 0, -1, 1);
        const projectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programLine, 'uProjectionMatrix');
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
        // }
        const gridPoints = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientWidth; i += gridSpace) {
            gridPoints.push(i, 0);
            gridPoints.push(i, canvas.clientHeight);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.clientHeight; i += gridSpace) {
            gridPoints.push(0, i);
            gridPoints.push(canvas.clientWidth, i);
        }

        const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        const color = gl.getUniformLocation(canvas.programLine, 'u_color');
        gl.uniform4f(color, 235 / 255, 237 / 255, 241 / 255, 1);

        const aSize = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programLine, 'a_Size');
        gl.vertexAttrib1f(aSize, gridSize);

        const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(canvas.programLine, 'aPosition');
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, gridPoints.length / 2);
    }
</script>

</html>
```